# Why can't Point and Rectangle be used as optional parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, geometry, arguments, optional-parameters

I'm trying to pass an optional argument to a geometry function, called `offset`, which may or may not be specified, but C# doesn't allow me to do any of the following. Is there a way to accomplish this?

- **Null as default**

  Error: A value of type '' cannot be used as a default parameter because there are no standard conversions to type 'System.Drawing.Point'

  ```
  public void LayoutRelative(.... Point offset = null) {}
  ```
- **Empty as default**

  Error: Default parameter value for 'offset' must be a compile-time constant

  ```
  public void LayoutRelative(.... Point offset = Point.Empty) {}
  ```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your default value doesn't require any special initialization, you don't need to use a nullable type or create different overloads.
You can use the `default` keyword:

```
public void LayoutRelative(.... Point offset = default(Point)) {}
```

If you want to use a nullable type instead:

```
public void LayoutRelative(.... Point? offset = null)
{
    if (offset.HasValue)
    {
        DoSomethingWith(offset.Value);
    }
}
```