# Point point = null as default parameter in class constructor

Tags: c#, .net

When i try to compile this simple code i get two errors in my contructor: "a value of type  cannot be used as a default parameter"
How can i solve this?

```
  public class PointerArgs
  {

      public Point Point { get; set; }


      public Point TransformedPoint { get; set; }


      public PointerArgs(Point point = null, Point transformedPoint = null)
      {
          this.Point = point;
          this.TransformedPoint = transformedPoint;
      }
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't Point and Rectangle be used as optional parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235653/why-cant-point-and-rectangle-be-used-as-optional-parameters)

Comment: Refer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235653/why-cant-point-and-rectangle-be-used-as-optional-parameters?lq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't set `Point` to `null` as it is value type.

Just do this:

```
public PointerArgs(Point point = default(Point), Point transformedPoint = default(Point))
{
   this.Point = point;
   this.TransformedPoint = transformedPoint;
}
```

You can assign it null by making it `Nullable` type, but that is unnecessary here.

Comment: ..you're probably going to need to do that to the other optional value type parameter too..

Comment: Now that you've made it nullable it won't be assignable to the non-nullable class level property.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead so should I leave it with `default(Point)`?

Comment: ..I would have.. it saves confusion for the OP (since they will get a compiler error from your answer).

Comment: No problem. Thanks for not taking my suggestion as an insult ... which a lot of people seem to be doing :) +1